# save method in a view

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a very simple model:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
 band = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
 instrument = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)

 def __unicode__ (self):
  return self.name
```

that I'm using as a model form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm 
from artistmod.artistcat.models import *

class ArtistForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model = Artist
```

but I can't seem to construct a view that will save the form data to the database. Currently I'm using:

```
def create_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ArtistForm(request.POST) 
            if form.is_valid(): 
                    form.save()
                    return render_to_response('display.html')
    else:
            form = ArtistForm()
    return render_to_response('create.html', {
        'form': form,
})
```

can anyone help the newbie?

Comment: What's the problem with the view? (Assuming it's not the indentation)

Comment: Off the top of my head, this looks just fine. Is there a view error, or are you not subsequently seeing the new object in the DB?

Comment: when you hit the "save" button on the template, it sends you to display.html (as it should) but it doesn't save the entered data to the database.

Comment: try:: artist = form.save(commit=False) print artist.name artist.save() print artist.id

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem resided in my template. I was using

```
    <form action="display/" method="POST">
```

as opposed to

```
    <form action="." method="POST">
```

also changed my HttpRequest object from `render_to_response`  to  `HttpResponseRedirect`

true newbie errors but at least it works now

Comment: Glad you solved it. I personally prefer `action=""` so you don't lose the querystring on the POST.

Comment: Changing form `action="thanks/"` to `action=" "` worked for me.