# Django: updating user with a form passes no error but does not change database

Tags: python, django, database, forms

Hey guys here is the code:

```
def updateProfile(request):
    context={}
    context['localUser'] = request.user

    instance = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
    form = ExtraForm(instance=instance)
    print (instance)
    print (form)

    if request.method=='POST':
        print ("hi")
        newForm = form.save(commit=False)
        newForm.research_place = request.POST.get("research_place")
        newForm.studies = request.POST.get("studies")
        # if newForm.is_valid():
            # print ("success)")
        print ("newform is ")
        print (newForm)
        print (newForm.research_place)
        print (newForm.studies)
        print (newForm.id)
        print (newForm.first_name)
        print (newForm.email)
        newForm.save()
    return render(request, "updateProfile.html",context)
```

It runs, and all of the values pass correctly. However, it doesn't save in the database. For reference, here is my ExtraForm form

```
class ExtraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RegisterUser
        fields = ['image','research_place','studies']
        widgets = {
            # 'image': ImageCropWidget,
        }
```

And this gets the RegisterUser model

```
class RegisterUser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    biography = models.CharField(max_length=1000000,blank=True)
    research_place = models.CharField(max_length=1000000,blank=True)
    studies = models.CharField(max_length=1000000,blank=True)

    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to='uploaded_images',default ="uploaded_images/defaultReal.jpg")
    # cropping = ImageRatioField('image','200x200',size_warning=True) #width x height

    avatar_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                    processors=[ResizeToFill(200, 200)],
                                    format='JPEG',
                                    options={'quality': 60})

    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("has_uploaded", ("Has uploaded")),
            ("is_authenticated", ("Is authenticated")),
        )
```

However in the HTML I am hardcoding the form with  because in this case it is just a little bit easier because i need to set the values of the inputs based on context variables i pass into the HTML template.

edit: I am also trying the following to no avail

```
instance = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
form = ExtraForm(request.POST or None,instance=instance)
print (instance)
print (form)

if request.method=='POST':
    print ("hi")
    # newForm = form.save(commit=False)
    form.research_place = request.POST.get("research_place")
    form.studies = request.POST.get("studies")
    if form.is_valid():
        print ("yes")
        form.save()
```

Comment: check out this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837229/how-do-i-save-data-from-a-modelform-to-database-in-django, I think that might help with the issue you are having

Comment: @Eli so I changed it to be more like the correct answer

 instance = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
 print (instance)

 if request.method=='POST':
  print ("hi")
  instance.research_place = request.POST.get("research_place")
  instance.studies = request.POST.get("studies")
                instance.save()

but this does not work either