# save file to database using django model forms and class based views

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Here is my models, views, forms and template. I need to save the document uploaded to database using `def form_valid()` method.

models.py:

```
def upload_qual_document_file_name(instance, filename):
    
    new_name = '%s.%s' % (uuid.uuid4(), filename.split('.')[-1])
    return 'core/upload_documents' + new_name


class Qual(models.Model):

    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None,null=False, blank=False)
    
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    document = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_qual_document_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
class QualUpdateView(CustomAdminMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Qual
   
    template_name = 'core/qual_form.django.html'
   
    form_class = QualUpdateForm
    
    context_object_name = 'qualification'

    def get_initial(self):

        initial = super(QualUpdateView, self).get_initial()
        initial['client'] = self.request.user.client
        return initial

    def get_queryset(self):

        return super(QualView, self).get_queryset().filter(client=self.request.user.client)
    

    def form_valid(self, form):
       
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
       
        self.object.client = self.request.user.client
       
          
        try:

            self.object.save()

        except IntegrityError:
            messages.error(self.request, 'Please check the complience updated.')
            return redirect(self.get_success_url())


        messages.success(self.request, 'Complience successfully updated.')
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        # messages.success(self.request, 'Qualification was successfully updated.')
        return reverse('qualification_list')
```

forms.py:

```
class QualUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.client = kwargs.get("initial", {}).get("client")
        super(QualUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
       
    def clean_name(self):
        client = self.client
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
       
        if name:
            try:
                data = Qual.objects.exclude(is_deleted=True).get(name=name,client_id=client)
            except Qual.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        else:
            pass
        return name
   

    class Meta:
        model = Qual
        fields = ['name','document']
        widgets = {
        'worker_renewal': SwitchCheckbox,
        }
```

template:

```
<form method="post" action="">

                {% csrf_token %}

                <fieldset class="add">

                    <legend>&nbsp;</legend>

                    <fieldset>
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}

                        <div class="control-group">

                            <label class="control-label pull-left" for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                {{ field }}
                            </div> <!--/controls-->
                            <p>{{ field.help_text }} </p>
                        </div> <!--/control-group-->
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </fieldset>

                <div id="form-buttons-container" class="form-actions">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Save Compliance">
                    
                    </div> <!--/form-actions-->
                </div>
            </form>
```

How can I save my file uploaded through template using django modelforms and classbased views?

Comment: Please note your Django version. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method may provide a useful reference.
Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837229/how-do-i-save-data-from-a-modelform-to-database-in-django